# UTL_RECOMP.RECOMP_SERIAL must be declared

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

First off I'd like to specify that I am trying to do this upgrade remotely. I am receiving this error:

> 2015-04-24:11:59:42 [Error] myDB - Failed to Recompile 'DBTYPE'
>   Database Objects: ExcSQL Failed: Oracle Error Encountered: ORA-06550:
>   line 1, column 7: PLS-00201: identifier 'UTL_RECOMP.RECOMP_SERIAL'
>   must be declared ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PL/SQL: Statement
>   ignored (6550) SQL Text: begin utl_recomp.recomp_serial('DBTYPE');
>   end;
>
> 2015-04-24:11:59:42 [Error] WorksObjects Execution Failed: DBTYPE -
>   Process JAR Files Failed: Failed to Recompile 'DBTYPE' Database
>   Objects:ExcSQL Failed: Oracle Error Encountered: ORA-06550: line 1,
>   column 7: PLS-00201: identifier 'UTL_RECOMP.RECOMP_SERIAL' must be
>   declared ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored (6550)
>   SQL Text: begin utl_recomp.recomp_serial('DBTYPE'); end;
>
> 2015-04-24:11:59:42 [Error] UPGD FAILED! : myDB - Upgrade Error -
>   Worker Thread Process Error - DBTYPE - Process JAR Files Failed:
>   Failed to Recompile 'DBTYPE' Database Objects:ExcSQL Failed: Oracle
>   Error Encountered: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PLS-00201: identifier
>   'UTL_RECOMP.RECOMP_SERIAL' must be declared ORA-06550: line 1, column
>   7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored (6550) SQL Text: begin
>   utl_recomp.recomp_serial('DBTYPE'); end;

when I try to do a recompile on invalid objects. The only thing I can find on the internet is that when recompiling, that I should be logged in as a sysdba, which I am currently doing.

```
"Data Source = (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = " + MyHostName + ")(PORT = 1521))(CONNECT_DATA =" +
"(SERVICE_NAME = " + mySID + ")));DBA Privilege = SYSDBA;" +
"User Id = " + MyID + ";Password = " + MyPW;
```

My connection is working correctly cause I can run 3/4 of the upgrade process till I hit this point where I try and recompile this specific schema.

```
Conn = GetConn( MyID, MyPW );
if (DevelopSrvr)
{
   ExcSQL(Conn, "alter session set plsql_debug=true");
}
ExcSQL(Conn, "begin utl_recomp.recomp_serial('" + schema + "'); end;");
```

This program runs fine locally and I have checked the stack trace and all the variables are returning the expected values.  Is there something I'm missing? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your output:

**"UTL_RECOMP.RECOMP_SERIAL' must be declared ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: "**

This message states that you are logged in but without sysdba privilege.

In your target database validate that:

1.) Remote login password file is set EXCLUSIVE

```
SQL> show parameter password

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
remote_login_passwordfile            string      EXCLUSIVE
```

2.) The username you are using to login is listed in v$pwfile_users catalog view (assume that you are connecting using "Z_TEST" database account as sysdba):

```
SQL> select username,sysdba from v$pwfile_users ;

USERNAME                       SYSDBA
------------------------------ -----
SYS                            TRUE
Z_TEST                         TRUE
```

The following example assumes "z_test/welcome1" account credentials and "db99" as target service name:

***sqlplus z_test/welcome1@db99 as sysdba***

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> begin
 2     utl_recomp.recomp_serial('Z_TEST');
 3  end;
 4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

TIP: when connected as sysdba your username becomes "SYS". Verify that in your code. As example:

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SYS"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Daniel!  I am connecting as sys to the server, but where I am getting caught up is I need to start sqlplus once connected correct?

Comment: when I mean connected as sysdba my C# application connects me to the server as sysdba and I am wondering if I have to open sqlplus from that point.  Wonder if its easier to run sqlplus locally and trying connecting that way. Feel like I doing double the work.

Comment: If you can run sqlplus locally it will no problem at all in running "utl_recomp.recomp_serial". The above example was performed executing "sqlplus" from a client machine (remotely).

Comment: Thanks for your time Daniel!  You helped point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Here are operational notes related to UTL_RECOMP package:

This package must be run using SQL*PLUS.

This package uses the job queue for parallel recompilation.

You must be connected AS SYSDBA to run this script.

This package expects the following packages to have been created with VALID status:

STANDARD (standard.sql)

DBMS_STANDARD (dbmsstdx.sql)

DBMS_JOB (dbmsjob.sql)

DBMS_RANDOM (dbmsrand.sql)

Comment: This list for the UTL_RECOMP package is complete because the application can run locally. The only thing I changed out of this package would be the connection to make it remote.

Comment: is there a command line argument I can pass with the "begin utl_recomp.recomp_serial('" + schema + "'); end;" to allow me  to execute the sql as a sysdba?

Comment: "sysdba" privilege is provided with account credentials during login process. I'm providing you an example as second answer.